# Docker Swarm consul not starting

Tags: docker, consul

When I try to start docker consul by this command

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d -p 8500:8500 -h consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

it gives the following error.

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
>   connectivity on endpoint tiny_bhaskara
>   (b53c9aa988d96750bfff7c19c6717b18756c7b92287f0f7a4d9e9fa81f42c43d):
>   iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0
>   --dport 8500 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8500 ! -i docker0: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

No idea what's going on!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37692662/596285):

Something on your system has removed the docker iptables entries that it needs to work. Two fixes have been suggested [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1871):

For CentOS:

```
sudo service docker restart
sudo service iptables save
```

And for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo service docker restart
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 # you may need to "sudo -s" to get a root shell first
```

After the restart of docker, you should see the docker chain under the nat table:

```
iptables -t nat -vL
```